# tuning feed item's table query with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, performance, tuning

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `rss_item` 
WHERE `feed_id` = 1 and `timestamp` < 1350698635 
ORDER BY `rss_item`.`timestamp` ASC
```

MySQL: 5.1; table engine: innodb

Explain result:

```
id  |  select_type  |  table     |  type   |  possible_keys  |  key        |  key_len |  ref     |  rows    |  Extra  
1   |  SIMPLE       |  rss_item  |  range  |  timestamp      |  timestamp  |  4       |  NULL    |  133534  |  Using where
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `rss_item2` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    `description` longtext NOT NULL,
    `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `url_crc` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `feed_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `goto` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`,`feed_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2425930 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This query with 400,000 rows takes 4 seconds. I added a composite index on `feed_id` and `timestamp` fields. How can I tune this query?

Comment: Hpw do you measure those 4 seconds?  Pushing so much data through a network connection can be slow.  A query plan would help anyway.

Comment: Yes, can you paste here your explain plan (EXPLAIN SELECT *  
FROM `rss_item...) we'll can see if MySQL use your index or not. I suspect MySQL take time on the "order by" clause.

Comment: @mfouilleul i add explain result in question, thank.

Comment: Ok, can you paste an "SHOW CREATE TABLE rss_item" ?

Comment: @mfouilleul look at question

Comment: The index you have is not the best. An index on `(feed_id, timestamp)` **might** be helpful, if used. If the query is to return 400K rows, MySQL might just decide to read the whole table, skip the non-matching rows and order the result.

Comment: Why is the mismatch between the plan and the text (133534 vs 400000 rows)?

Answer (score -1):

I dont know about feed_id but your timestamp column by definition have probably many differents values. I will advise you to try to create a simple index on timestamp column.

Do you have "disparate" values too on feed_id column?

For me you should take your attention on the timestamp column (WHERE + ORDER BY). Maybe it'll not a index problem, maybe your MySQL instance have some difficulties to sort the result (bad temp table management) so you can try without ORDER BY clause to see its impact.

Let me know.

Max.